# sql queries using too many resources

Tags: mysql

My host has said one of my sites is using too many sql minutes.
I have a list of sql queries (20 in total) which are using the most system resources.

The information starts

```
'civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_50974519e3a17388f13e9f857d1c2320'
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `database_civicrm`.`civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_50974519e3a17388f13e9f857d1c2320`
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_contact'
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `database_civicrm`.`civicrm_contact`
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_activity_contact'
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `database_civicrm`.`civicrm_activity_contact`
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_activity'
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `database_civicrm`.`civicrm_activity`
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_group_contact'
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `database_civicrm`.`civicrm_group_contact`
```

How can I match this information up with something my civicrm is doing? This query has run for 172seconds and run 1239 times - although I'm not sure over what time period.

Thanks
Caroline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gccache one is group contact cache. You probably have a cron job that rebuilds the group contact cache periodically, or it can also happen when the cache expires.

The other ones come from either

- converting to utf8mb4, which you probably only ran once but it would have run on every table
- turning on advanced logging (administer - system settings - misc) which also you probably would have only turned on once, but it will also partially run when you do something like add a custom field

Comment: Thanks Demerit. Can I ask a foillow up? I did once turn on advance logging but it is turned off now and I think I did convert to  utf8mb4. Are you saying that these thongs will still be impacting on the sql minutes?

Comment: Ok, then those two shouldn't anymore.